# Switching to a virtual terminal is slow

Tags: console

When switching to a virtual terminal using e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, it takes about a second to switch. Not too horrible for something that's typically rarely used, but I would like to use it more and it's substantially slower than, say, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. It's particularly weird since switching back to the desktop environment (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> for me) is instant.

I've noticed it before, but currently I'm running Debian testing (Stretch) with Cinnamon 2.8.7 on X 1.18.3. The resolution of the virtual terminal is the same as X's resolution.

What is this delay caused by and how can I improve it?

Comment: Works pretty great for me :).  You need to say what software + hardware you're using!

Comment: @sourcejedi Hmm I've noticed it on every Linux-based OS ever, but I'll include that.

Comment: My "good" system is Fedora 23 on Thinkpad X201, and it just feels *instant*.  The resolution is the same on X (`xdpyinfo`) & console (`fbset`).  Pre-KMS, you tended to suffer long mode-changes switching *either* way.  Exception: switching *to* gdm (which has its own VT) flickers once - it does take about a second overall but nothing more than that.  I don't know the root cause, but I note that gdm (on Fedora) is different in that it runs as Wayland instead of X.

Comment: @sourcejedi I also run X (added the info to the post) and the resolution is also the same. If it wasn't I think I'd also have a delay switching back from the vt to the desktop environment.

Comment: what GPU and driver are you using?  i have nvidia cards using the proprietary nvidia driver, and also have delays of over a second when switching from X to VT and vice-versa....annoying, but I don't do it often so it's not a big deal for me.

Comment: @cas Nvidia indeed, not sure what driver. How can I look that up? (I tried `dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia` but the only result is some `libnvtt2`, some texture tools.) I do remember something about `nouveau`, I see that popping up regularly in `dmesg`, that could be it.

Comment: ok, i suspected it might have something to do with the proprietary nvidia driver, but if you're using nouveau then that can't be the case.

Comment: @cas You mention instant. Do you mean the screen instantly goes black and after a very short (but visible) delay the text appears? Because that's what it does for me.

Comment: umm, i didn't mention instant at all.  if, while in X, i press Ctrl-Alt-F1, I get about a half-second delay, then a switch to a blank console, another delay of maybe a second, and then I see the text on my console.  Switching back to X with Alt-F5, it switches instantly to a blank VT5  followed by a delay of about a second before my X session is displayed.  I have no idea what causes these delays - never cared enough to bother finding out.

Comment: @cas Oh sorry, I misremebered, sourcejedi mentioned that it feels instant. My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X server manages the state of the graphics card when it's active. When you switch between X and a text console or back, the graphics card needs to be reinitialized. Depending on the graphics card and on how it's used, there may be an unavoidable delay. A 1s delay is on the high side but not unreasonable.

Few people use a text console, so even if it was possible to improve the transition time (which it might not be), this isn't a high priority for developers.

If this delay is really a problem, try changing the driver or the configuration in X, in text consoles or both. If you're using a proprietary driver, use the free driver, or vice versa. If you're using a framebuffer console, don't, or vice versa. Some options that can affect what needs to be reinitialized when the console switches owners; I don't know what to look for in particular.

Comment: How/to what would I change the "framebuffer console"? Searching for "virtual console no framebuffer" and "switch framebuffer console" yield no good results it seems (at least on DDG).

Comment: @Luc There are multiple ways to parametrize the console. At least the `vga=…` and `fbcon=…` kernel parameters, `/etc/default/console-setup`. I haven't really use VGA consoles for a long time so I don't know the modern ways.